# Update the Table Cell Data from other table DidSelect methods

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with With two `UITexField` inside. And `Second UITableView` With `two UILabel` inside.

Check image.

[image]

Now Want I want when User Click on the `Add Button`. Menu popUp with a `table View` (called `tblPassList`) Now when the user select the Row the `Name` and `Age` Will Update to that particular Cell.

This What I have Done but its update only on First Cell.Check image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EdoC.png)

> var name2 = ""
>
> var age2 = ""

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cellToReturn = UITableViewCell()
            if tableView == tblOnWard {
                let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblOnward", for: indexPath) as! TblOnward
                Cell.selectionStyle = .none
                Cell.shawdow(viewShadow: Cell.ViewCell)
                Cell.lblSeatNo.text = "Seat No. " + arrSeatNoOnward[indexPath.row]
                Cell.lblHead.text = ArrHeadTitle[indexPath.row]
                Cell.txtName.text =  self.name2
                Cell.txtAge.text = self.age2
                self.age2 = ""
                self.name2 = ""
                cellToReturn = Cell
            }
           return cellToReturn
}
```

> DidSelect

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView == tblPassList {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! GetpassList
            name2 = cell.lblName.text!
            age2 = cell.lblAge.text!
            self.tblReturn.reloadData()
            self.tblOnWard.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: You create a model with name2 and age2 then set value to model object and add that model into an array. While reloading **tblOnWard** read value from the model which is in array.

Comment: Yes. But why is always update the value on 0 index. Even i press the add button of second cell

Comment: Could you please update your question with more clarification because I don't know what you are doing after button press.

Comment: After Button Press the bottom table popUp and on `DidSelect method` I want `Name` and `Age` string add into the `TextField' of cell on which i press the button